# Django/Python change content.innerHTML to a src page

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, iframe

I am running a page that on a click, replaces the content in an iFrame. The JS in index.js looks like this:

```
if (page == 'stationData') {
    content.innerHTML = '<h1>Station Data</h1>';
      content.innerHTML += '<iframe class="site_data_tab"  src="stationDataHTML.html"></iframe>';
  }
```

The old iFrame data goes away and the text "Station Data" appears as expected, but I can't figure out how to get the stationDataHTML.html page to appear in the iFrame.

I've tried something like this:

index.js:

```
if (page == 'stationData') {
content.innerHTML = '<h1>Station Data</h1>';
  content.innerHTML += '<iframe class="site_data_tab"  src="{% url \'data-stationData\' %}"></iframe>';
```

}

urls.py:

```
 urlpatterns = [path('', AboutView.as_view(template_name="stationDataHTML.html")),]
```

views.py:

```
class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "stationDataHTML.html"
```

When I run, and I click the button to change the iframe content, I recevie and error 
 
Not Found: /data/stationDataHTML.html 
[02/Sep/2021 16:02:04] "GET /data/stationDataHTML.html HTTP/1.1" 404 6279

Is there a a way to change the iframe content to a locally hosted page? (stationDataHTML.html)